# Domain name resolution for NodeMCU as an access point

Tags: networking, dns, wifi, nodemcu, access-point

I was reading through the NodeMCU documentation on `enduser setup Module`, and now I have a little confusion about the following statement:

```
Connect to that SSID and then navigate to the root of any website (e.g., http://example.com/... 
A web page will load, allowing the end user to provide their Wi-Fi information.
```

With default configuration, the NodeMCU access point has an IP address: `192.168.4.1.`

My question is, how is `www.example.com` resolved so that it points to the module's access point IP address `(192.168.4.1)`? Is there any default DNS configuration for the module?

Full documentation is available [here](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/enduser-setup/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply always returns the IP of the ESP for every DNS query.
[You can see that in line 1491 of the source code. (enduser_setup.c)](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/d9b3db06f6486505f215efdc04abda2f45a1cdee/app/modules/enduser_setup.c#L1491)

The [enduser_setup_dns_recv_callback](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/d9b3db06f6486505f215efdc04abda2f45a1cdee/app/modules/enduser_setup.c#L1427) will always return the IP that is being retrieved by calling `wifi_get_ip_info`.

[Line 1470:](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/d9b3db06f6486505f215efdc04abda2f45a1cdee/app/modules/enduser_setup.c#L1470)

```
wifi_get_ip_info(if_index , &ip_info)
```

[Line 1491:](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/d9b3db06f6486505f215efdc04abda2f45a1cdee/app/modules/enduser_setup.c#L1491)

```
c_memcpy(&(dns_reply[insert_byte]), &(ip_info.ip), 4);
```